# SFML Player moves faster when I move my mouse

Tags: c++, sfml

I am new to SFML and was following a tutorial. However, I have encountered a very strange bug. I have a simple script that runs player.move whenever press WASD.
Although this script works, the player moves at extremely slow speeds. However, when I move my mouse while moving, it moves at a correct speed.
I have Visual Studio 2022 and SFML 2.6.

I researched a lot of issues on the internet but could not find anyone who had a similar issue.
My code is

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "SFML Tutorial", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Resize);
    sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 100.0f));
    player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)) {
            switch (evnt.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::Resized:
                printf("New Window Width: %i New Window Height: %i\n", evnt.size.width, evnt.size.height);
                break;
            case sf::Event::TextEntered:
                if (evnt.text.unicode < 128) {
                    printf("%c", evnt.text.unicode);
                }
            }

            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A)) {
                player.move(-0.1f, 0.0f);
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D)) {
                player.move(0.1f, 0.0f);
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W)) {
                player.move(0.0f, -0.1f);
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S)) {
                player.move(0.0f, 0.1f);
            }
            window.clear();
            window.draw(player);
            window.display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't see anywhere where I detect mouse movement, so I am very confused by this issue.

Comment: I can recommend reading this article: [Fix Your Timestep!](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to measure how much time that has passed since the last time you iterated in the main input loop and then use that time to multiply the player's movement. Also, don't check if the keys are pressed down inside the `while (window.pollEvent(evnt))` loop.

Something like this:

```cpp
sf::Clock clock;
float time{};

while (window.isOpen()) {
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A)) {
        player.move(-10.0f * time, 0.0f);                    // multiply
    }

    // ... do the same on the rest too ...

    time = clock.restart().asSeconds(); // last thing in the loop
}
```

It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 512), "SFML Tutorial",
                            sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Resize);
    window.setFramerateLimit(120); // not strictly needed

    sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 100.0f));
    player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    sf::Clock clock;
    float time{};
    float speed = 10.0f;

    while(window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event evnt;
        while(window.pollEvent(evnt)) {
            switch(evnt.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A)) {
            player.move({-speed * time, 0.0f});
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D)) {
            player.move({speed * time, 0.0f});
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W)) {
            player.move({0.0f, -speed * time});
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S)) {
            player.move({0.0f, speed * time});
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
        time = clock.restart().asSeconds();
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to break the entire script. The first time I ran it it worked, but still stayed slow. And then it just didn't work at all. I'm not sure what happened. I have the code
`
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A)) {
    player.move(-1.0f * time, 0.0f);
   }
   if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D)) {
    player.move(1.0f * time, 0.0f);
   }
   if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W)) {
    player.move(0.0f, -1.0f * time);
   }
   if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S)) {
    player.move(0.0f, 1.0f * time);
   }
`

Comment: as well as
`
time = clock.restart().asSeconds();
`
at the end

Comment: @TheCrazyCreeper If it's slow, you need to increase the multiplier. Make it `10.0f` instead of `1.0f` and it will be 10 times faster. The point is that will will move at the same speed independent of what hardware you run it on or what else that your computer is doing. Do you also do the key-press-check outside of the `pollEvent` loop? I can't say why it worked the first time but not the next. It works every time for me.

Comment: No I mean it genuinly isn't moving, not like it isn't moving very fast. Also, as I am very new to SFML this is my only file and all checks and code I am running are above

Comment: @TheCrazyCreeper I put a full example of my suggested fixes in the answer. It runs smoothly for me and the player is moves around fine.

Comment: I don't know what I did differently, but that fixed it. Thanks!